# Applying function after React Hook has completed synchronously

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am building a react component as a functional component.
I am gonna narrow it down here to a minimal problem, you can imagine it as a DataGrid containing data that is fetched from an external API which is saved to that state so that it can be used for the DataGrid.

```
[orders, setOrders]  = React.useState(getSomeIntialValuesToShowWhileFetching())
```

Then I have the useEffect hook to run only on mounting to fetch the data.

```
useEffect(() => {
let res = await getDataFromApi();
setOrders(res);

}, [])
```

So far so good. Now I have another calculation, that needs to be done after orders was filled with the data, think of it as a total of all orders.
How do I achieve this, due to the async nature of  `setOrders(res)` ?

I tried using another useEffect, that has orders in its dependency array. The problem here is that this also runs on the inital mounting of the component.

As setOrders is asynchronously but does not return a Promise, I don´t see a way to await it or chain it with then operations.

I am grateful for answers as I am still learning how to deal with hooks.

Comment: Have an effect/memo/etc dependent on `orders`? Do the calculation on `res` before even setting `orders`? Hard to say what makes sense w/o context.

Comment: Yeah thanks, you´re right, doing the res calculation before writing it to orders can possibly avoid the problem in my particular use case. But is there any solution to this problem as it does not seem to be such a rare use case? As I mentioned, my problem with using an effect dependent on orders is that I need to avoid running this effect on mounting

Comment: Personally I'd either pre-load the initial values, or set it them empty and render something appropriate until there's data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another UseEffect that has orders in its dependency array, but with a conditional that checks if orders received any value. Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (orders.length < 1 ) {
  return;
}
// get total orders
}, [orders]);
```

Comment: Yeah this is appropriate if the business logic allows a check like orders.length > 0. In my specific use case and context that is shown here that would probably not be applicable as the list of orders keeps stuff that is shown has some items (Yes I see this could be solved in the business logic). But in more general terms, is there a possibility to check this not depending on business logic but on something the framework offers?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a custom hook known as `useDidUpdateEffect`. In essence, it is a normal `useEffect` but slightly modified to skip the initial render.

It uses the `didMountRef` as a flag, which is false on init. Hence your function will run only if `didMountRef.current == true` which happens after the initial render.

That way your calculation will only run when your dependency(`orders`) actually updates.

---

**Hook definition**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useDidUpdateEffect(fn, deps) {
  const didMountRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMountRef.current) { 
      return fn();
    }
    didMountRef.current = true;
  }, deps);
}
```

**Usage**

```
import { useDidUpdateEffect } from '/your/hooks/path';

useDidUpdateEffect( () => {
    calculation();
}, [orders] )
```